# hook into ajax success later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a plugin , there is an ajax call which displays the data to user.

If user wants to add some js on ajax success? can he do it from his js script , like target this ajax success event. 
For example:

```
 $(document).on('click','button',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url.php',
        success: function(response){
            /** HOOK HERE **/
            $('.display').html(response);
        }
    })
})
```

Now user wants to add this `alert('User data');` to ajax success call

Comment: You should probably provide them with a possibility to pass in their own callback function as a parameter. https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/#provide-callback-capabilities

Comment: If you're making this a *plugin* then your plugin will have options, not just some basic js (which I'm assuming has been excluded for the sake of brevity in the question).  Simply add it as one of the options when initialising the plugin and use `$.isFunction(options.onSuccess) { options.onSuccess(); }` (or whatever you call it)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remember that functions are objects just like numbers, strings etc. So you can provide a variable for him to attach a function to and call that if available:

```
MyPlugin = {
    onAjaxSuccess: null
};

$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url.php',
        success: function(response){
            /** HOOK HERE **/
            if (typeof MyPlugin.onAjaxSuccess == 'function') {
                MyPlugin.onAjaxSuccess(response);
            }
            $('.display').html(response);
        }
    })
})
```

So now your users can do:

```
MyPlugin.onAjaxSuccess = function (response) {
    console.log(response)
};
```

## Wait, where have I seen this before?

This is a similar API to the old-school DOM `.onXXX` callbacks. Just like

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
    alert('HA');
};
```

## Looks too old-school.

If you want your API to look a bit more modern and all fancy you can emulate jQuery's style:

```
MyPlugin = {
    onAjaxSuccess: null,
    on: function (e_type,callback) {
        if (e_type == 'ajaxSuccess') {
            this.onAjaxSuccess = callback;
        }
    }
};
```

Now your users can do this:

```
MyPlugin.on('ajaxSuccess',function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```